# C# - SQL Query Rounding Problem while adding DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, sqlcommand

I have an SQL query and it has comma value. When I adding it to DataGridView I want to this format `(#, ##).`  I tried `Math.Round()` function but it doesn't work.

Below is the query I have tried:

```
(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), column3)*100) as normalize
```

It's my C# code for adding;

```
dgv.Rows.Add(rows["column1"].ToString() + " " + rows["column2"].ToString(), rows["column3"], "%" + "" + Math.Round(Convert.ToSingle(rows["normalize"].ToString())), 2);
```

It runs without comma with this code. Normally, If I don't use Math.Round it works like this format (#, ####).

And I tried this one also;

```
dgv.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add the value type property, it works on my case.

```
dgv.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
dgv.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Double);
```

Full code sample

```
object[] row = new object[] { 6.54553 };

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";

dataGridView1.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(double);
```

Comment: dgv.Columns[2].ValueType = GetType(Double); this row gives error for Double. 'represents a double precision floating point number'